# Cannot assign role to a node on Chef bootstrap

Tags: azure, chef-infra

I am bootstrapping a node using the Azure Chef Extension. I pass it a validation.pem (to create the node) and the client.rb to pass the org information to it. During this process, I would like to assign a role to that node but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I can pass a runlist ([role:"my_role"]) but this only runs once and doesn't actually assign it at the server level. The only way I know how to do this is using the knife command. I don't really want to do this because when I bootstrap the machine using the Azure Extension, it's asynchronous - I don't know when it actually completes. I can't edit the node using the knife command until after it completes so this makes automating this process difficult. Can I create node and assign node to the role all in one shot? Can I pass the role assignment info inside the client.rb?

Comment: How do you pass the runlist ? I suspect you're using a `-o`  instead of `-r`, o is for override (and don't save the runlist back to the chef-server) and r is to replace the run-list at end of run (but only if the run was successful)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [knife azure plugin](https://github.com/chef/knife-azure)?

I'm not a windows guy, but these cloud plugins should support the standard bootstrap options. Try the following:

```
knife azure server create  ... --run-list 'role[myrolegohere]'
```

Comment: Nope, not using the the knife azure plugin. Just using the azure-cli xplat tools (node.js) to enable the extension and pass in client.rb and validator.pem. I will check out the plugin and see if it does what i need it to. 
PS - I never mentioned Windows (this is Linux) but makes no diff. Commands are the same